# Build procedure hangs in release mode in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2019, release-mode

I have a commercial software with several projects. The build procedure in visual studio just hangs when it reaches the file shown in the picture. I have not changed that file since the last successful run,
the code runs on debug mode and of course I receive no error in release mode.

[image]

I have tried to clean and rebuild all the separate projects and it always stops on that file.
Do you have any suggestions I should try ?

edit: I found the problem and posting the solution in case someone has a similar problem.
In my case the problem was not on the builder but on the linker that followed. The way I constructed the include files made my project too big and the linking time was taking for ever(over 11 hours). I had to manually change the host-linker to 64 bits (for some reason the default in my system was the 32 bit) and rearrange the includes and the problem was solved.

I had a similar problem with this guy https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/109963/linker-with-incremental-and-trackerexe-extremly-sl.html

Comment: Just a *suggestion*: Try reducing the maximum number of parallel project builds (Tools->Options->Build & Run).

Comment: That was set to the maximum threads of my computer (12). I reduced it to 8, it took longer time to reach to the spot where it hangs but unfortunately it still stopped responding. It is weird, the CPU is at 100% usage up to this point and then it goes down to 27%. Also all the processes of Visual Studio occupy 0& of the CPU at that time, except the incremental linker process.

Comment: Does more than one of the projects include the `NodeGraphicsItem.cpp` file? If so, you *may* need to reduce the thread-count even further, or otherwise prevent those projects being built simultaneously. Try using just 1 thread ... I know that will take time, but that may, at least, identify the problem (which can then be reported to the VS team).

Comment: I have the same problem, could not solve the issue even my project is using x64 build, any idea that can solve this issue? It just stop after compiling a quarter of the codes, I tried deleting that cpp file where it stopped, it will still stop at the next cpp file

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting an answer from the question itself as it wasn't obvious to me that there was a solution when I first scrolled down.

> ...The problem and posting the solution in case someone has a similar problem. In my case the problem was not on the builder but on the linker that followed. The way I constructed the include files made my project too big and the linking time was taking for ever (over 11 hours). I had to manually change the host-linker to 64 bits (for some reason the default in my system was the 32 bit) and rearrange the includes and the problem was solved.